# Update values in array in C

Tags: c, arrays

Assume 2 tables B and Y. Each containing 3 elements. I want to update array `Y` with the values of array `B`, so that eventually `B[i]=Y[i]`. I have come up with the following code. I would expect it for  `i=0` to perform the retrieve and update function, so that `B[0]=Y[0]`, then move on to `i=1` (retrieve and update, so that `B[1]=Y[1]`) and finally move on to `i=2` (retrieve and update, so that `B[2]=Y[2]`).

Instead, firstly it retrieves all values from `B` (performs `retrieve` function 3 times consecutively, ie first `b=B[0]`, then `b=B[1]` and last `b=B[2]`) and since the last value of `b` is `b=B[2]`, it passes that value with the function `update` (which is performed next 3 times consecutively) to all positions in array `Y`. So it ends up with `Y[0]=Y[1]=Y[2]=b=B[2]`. Any ideas for the rookie? Thanks!

```
for (i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    b = retrieve (B, b, i);
    y[i] = update(y, b, i);

float retrieve (float B[], float b, int i)
{
for (i = 0; i < 3; i++)
     b = B[i];
     return (b);
}

float update(float y[], float b, int i)
{
for (i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    y[i] = b;
    return (y[i]);
}
```

Comment: That first for-statement will only execute the line `b = retrieve (B, b, i);`.  Based on the indentation, this doesn't appear to be your intention.  Perhaps you are missing some curly braces?

Comment: There's no need for loops in the functions. It should just be `return B[i]`. And there's no need for `b` to be a parameter to the `retrieve` function.

Comment: A function can only return once. If you return inside a loop, the loops stops. So you're always returning `B[0]`.

Comment: ***Pro tip of the day*** - install a ***debugger*** and learn how to use it to ***singe step*** your code, often even the output of a function is not what you think it should be

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can perform this in many manners, I am writing below code in very basic way. It will help you to understand clearly. I am pasting the complete code which I run to test.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>

float retrieve (float *arrB, int i)
{// this method return ith value of B
   return arrB[i];
}

void update(float *arrY, float b, int i)
{//thi method update value b to the ith index of Y
    arrY[i] = b;
}

void main()
{
  float B[3] = {2.1,3.6,5.7};//for testing
  float Y[3];
  float b;
  int i;
   for (i = 0; i < 3; i++)
   {
    b = retrieve (B, i);
    update(Y, b, i);
   }
   //below line to check value of Y for testing
   for(i=0; i<3; i++)
    printf("%f ",Y[i]);
   getch();
}
```

Hope this will help you.
If you want to send b in retrieve function and want it to bring value for you, then you may send its address, check the below code. but return does not make sense so i removed, if you want return then put it.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>

void retrieve (float *arrB, float *b, int i)
{
   *b = arrB[i];
   /*return does not make any sense, so you have to decide
   to keep it or not*/
}

float update(float *arrY, float b, int i)
{
    arrY[i] = b;
    return arrY[i];
    /*return does not make any sense, so you have to decide
   to keep it or not*/
}

void main()
{
  float B[3] = {2.1,3.6,5.7};
  float Y[3];
  float b;
  int i;
   for (i = 0; i < 3; i++)
   {
    retrieve (B, &b, i);
    update(Y, b, i);
   }
   //below line to check value of Y
   for(i=0; i<3; i++)
    printf("%f ",Y[i]);
   getch();
}
```

Comment: Υου are all awesome! Solved! Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

You are missing braces `{}` when you call the function (with correct indentation it is easy to spot the problem)

```
for (i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    b = retrieve (B, b, i);
y[i] = update(y, b, i);
```

should be

```
for (i = 0; i < 3; i++){
    b = retrieve (B, b, i);
    y[i] = update(y, b, i);
}
```

The function

```
float retrieve (float B[], float b, int i)
{
  for (i = 0; i < 3; i++)
     b = B[i];
  return (b);
}
```

makes no sense as it assign b three times but only uses the last and returns it, to put the return inside of the loop makes no sense either. Maybe you should not have another `for`-loop here.

Maybe if you combine it as

```
for (i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    b = B[i];
    y[i] = b;
}
```

or even shorter

```
for (i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    y[i] = B[i];
}
```

it will achieve what you are trying to do

Comment: Thanks for the advice! I entered the missing braces and skipped return from the 2 functions. Still, it does not give me the desired result. I know that b parameter is not necessary, but for the purpose of the exercise, I must use a b parameter and must use update and retrieve functions.

Comment: #include <stdio.h>

float retrieve(float[], float, int);
float update(float[], float, int);

void main (float b)
{
 int i;
 
 float B[3], y[3];


 for(i  = 0 ; i < 3; i++) 
 {
        printf("Enter value for array B: \n");
        scanf("%f", &B[i]);
 }

 printf("\nValues in array B:\n");

    for (i = 0; i < 3; i++)
 printf("%f\n", B[i]);


    for (i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        b = retrieve(B, b, i);
     y[i] = update(y, b, i);
}

Comment: printf("\nValues in array y using RETRIEVE and UPDATE functions:\n");
 for (i = 0; i < 3; i++) 
 {
  printf("%f\n", y[i]);
    }
}

float retrieve(float B[], float b, int i){

 for (i = 0; i < 3; i++)
     b = B[i];
}

float update(float y[], float b, int i){

 for (i = 0; i < 3; i++)
     y[i] = b;
}